# Need assistance regarding core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to core data and trying to create a simple apps using core data. I am currently working on app to save data in to-many relationship, there are several questions and tutorials but I am still confused.

I have two entities **person** and **contactNumbers**, I am fetching person and its contact numbers from address book, person **A** has mobile number, iphone number, home, work, other... which creates to-many relationship.

In my code I didnt subclass any entity, Is it necessary to subclass entities to save data in relationship? I am asking this because I have read that its not necessary to subclass direct working with NSManagedObject class will do the job.

All I want is to save person **A** first name, last name in **person entity** and its contact numbers in **contactNumbers entity**. How to save data in to-many relationship using core data?

Please I request do not refer other stackoverflow questions, raywenderlich tutorial, app code blog tutorials etc.

Please provide a clearly understandable code with concepts to deal this situation. Thanks a lot.

***This is my model***

[image: This is my model]

if I Do this

```
NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[person setValue:@"first name A" forKey:@"firstName"];
[person setValue:@"last name B" forKey:@"lastName"];
[person setValue:@"123" forKey:@"mobile"];
```

I got this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObject 0x82abcc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Person is not key value coding-compliant for the key "mobile".
```

If i do this

```
NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [person setValue:@"first name A" forKey:@"firstName"];
    [person setValue:@"last name B" forKey:@"lastName"];    

    NSManagedObject *contactNumber = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ContactNumber" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [contactNumber setValue:@"123" forKey:@"home"];
    [contactNumber setValue:@"456" forKey:@"iPhone"];
    [contactNumber setValue:@"789" forKey:@"mobile"];
    [contactNumber setValue:@"111" forKey:@"work"];
    [contactNumber setValue:@"112" forKey:@"other"];
```

its working fine, but how data got related to each other in two entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to subclass.

You just need relations.

Make a relation on `Person` named `contactNumbers` that points to the `ContactNumber` entity, and a matching relation on `ContactNumber` entity called `person` that points back to person.

The `contactNumber` relation should be one to many (because one person has many contacts), while the relation from `ContactNumber` going back to `Person` should be one to one (because each contact entry will appear in only one person).

When you get a `Person` entity then, you'll be able to get a set of ContactNumber objects from the `contactNumbers` property, and then look through elements in the set.  Or you can search `ContactNumber` entities where the `person` ID matches the person relation going back to `Person`.

**Followup**: Your first code does not work because you cannot reference a single instance through a set.

Your second section of code is fine, just add the line

```
contactNumber.person = person;
```

Then you can access the set of contacts from a person at any time with:

```
NSSet *contacts = person.contactNumbers;
```

And get the contact number you want.  You cannot go directly from a person to one contact without some very tricky keypath stuff.

I would EXTREMELY STRONGLY suggest using [Mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to generate data objects after you set up the model, it makes the data clearer as to how you can use it.  Using the setKey mechanism with Core Data is UTTERLY INSANE.

Comment: thanks for replying, my relationship is set exactly the same way. I didnt get your 2nd last point. Please provide a code snippet. I currently have no records in core data, I am doing it like this NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName:@"person" inManagedObjectContext:context]; and did same for contactNumbers... and set both entities properties and called save method, but how data is related, I think the way I am doing the data is saving independently from each other, no relationship between them.

Comment: Can't really provide any code without seeing your data model.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, I am trying to understand the new code, I am a newbie to core data so all I am trying to is learn the basic and to get firm grip on concepts so handling complicating situations becomes easy. I dont know is it good or bad habit, when I start new topic I study it from scratch basic to advance not just the problem domain in which I am stuck.

Comment: contactNumber.person this person is relationship and = person means the entity? NSSet *contacts = person.contactNumbers;? sorry :( but I am still confused, whats going under the hood I can't understand. First contactNumber.person then person.contactNumbers I am totally confused. Please I request a step by step explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I've helped you all I can.  If you cannot understand the code I wrote you really should just buy a book on CoreData and work through the explanations in there, until you understand the basics.  This code is at the most basic level, if you can't follow this nothing else I write will help.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do any subclassing at all to read and write Core Data relationships (or any other values for that matter). In Core Data, a relationship is represented as an NSMutableSet. Here is some sample code to show you how to retrieve this set and modify it:

```
// Assuming myPerson is an NSManagedObject instance of the Person entity
NSMutableSet *contactNumbers = [myPerson mutableSetValueForKey:@"contactNumbers"];

// Add numbers normally by calling the set's addObject property
[contactNumbers addObject:myNewNumber];
//etc.
```

I would also highly recommend taking a look at the Sensible TableView framework if you haven't already done so. The framework will automatically generate the UI for you Core Data entities, including all relationships. It will also automatically handle adding/removing new relationship objects. I myself wouldn't imagine going back to doing stuff manually again without it. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for replying, Sensible TableView framework makes me excited :) its awesome, but as a learner I want to do all the manual work.

Comment: Great! Wishing you all the best with your learning journey! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot but right now I need a code snippet to understand this issue. Kendall Helmstetter Gelner asked for data model and code, so I am updating in my question. I also asking you for bit detailed help.